# How to build Appium Desktop from source code?

Tags: appium, appium-ios, appium-desktop

I'm trying to build the "latest" version of Appium Desktop from source (on a Mac), but I'm clearly not doing something that I need to be doing, because no binary is generated after I run all the build commands.

So, I've downloaded and unpacked the .zip archive https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/archive/v1.16.0.zip, opened up a terminal session inside the root of the source directory, and followed the online instructions for building from source--but I think this is for the server build https://appium.io/docs/en/contributing-to-appium/appium-from-source/#running-appium-from-source

```
npm install
npm run build
node .
```

And it all appears to work successfully! I get a "build completed" message and life looks fab, but nothing launches as far as an app is concerned, and I can find no .app file anywhere in the source directory. And, oddly, there are no build instructions to be found anywhere in the source directory. There's a "ReadMe.md" file but it provides no instructions on how to build from source.

Can someone please tell me what I need to do to build and launch Appium Desktop (not the server) from source? (Oh, I also ran appium-doctor and it gave me a clean bill of health.)

Any feedback would be most appreciated!

Thanks,

Wulf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already run `npm install` so it should be as simple as running `npm run dev` if you want it in dev mode or `npm start` if you want non-dev.

See the [Contributing to Appium Desktop readme](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) for more.